# How to make an Async/await fetch post? getting 500 internal server error

Tags: javascript, php, rest, post, fetch

I have succesfuly made a fetch post to my php api with my thisWorks() function, but I am trying to use fetch with async/await post () function but I keep getting back a 500 internal server error response when trying to do this which I'm not sure how to debug since my code in my async function is mostly the same as in thisWorks().

here are the two functions -

```
//I can make a succesful post to my api with this function and it returns a 200 ok response from the server

function thisWorks(title, message, author, id) {
    fetch("http://menu.com/menu/api/post/create.php", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: new Headers(),

      body: JSON.stringify({
        'title' : title,
        'body' : message,
        'author' : author,
        'category_id' : id
      })
    })
    .then( (response) => {
       console.log(response);
    });
}


//this gives a 500 internal server error and  TypeError: "NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource."

const post = async (title, message, author, id) => {

    const location = "http://menu.com/menu/api/post/create.php";

    const settings = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }),
        body: JSON.stringify({
            'title' : title,
            'body' : message,
            'author' : author,
            'category_id' : id
        })
    };

    try {
        const response = await fetch(location, settings);
        const json = await response.json();
        console.log(json);
        return json;
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return error;
    }
}
```

Before I was getting the same 500 internal server error in thisWorks and the errorLog in my apache server was the same errors I'm now getting in my async post function which is this -

```
[Sun Feb 17 18:21:11.122109 2019] [php7:warn] [pid 890] [client 127.0.0.1:37548] PHP Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/menu/api/post/create.php on line 7

[Sun Feb 17 18:21:11.122452 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 890] [client 127.0.0.1:37548] PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'title' of non-object in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/menu/api/post/create.php on line 22

[Sun Feb 17 18:21:11.122471 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 890] [client 127.0.0.1:37548] PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'body' of non-object in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/menu/api/post/create.php on line 23

[Sun Feb 17 18:21:11.122477 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 890] [client 127.0.0.1:37548] PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'author' of non-object in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/menu/api/post/create.php on line 24

[Sun Feb 17 18:21:11.122482 2019] [php7:notice] [pid 890] [client 127.0.0.1:37548] PHP Notice: Trying to get property 'category_id' of non-object in /home/orpheus/Practice_dev/menu/api/post/create.php on line 25

[Sun Feb 17 18:21:11.122743 2019] [php7:error] [pid 890] [client 127.0.0.1:37548] PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'category_id' at row 1 in /home/orpheu$
```

The issue was not one in my php code, but it was with my fetch request and I solved it by adding new Headers() to the request and it worked. So I'm sure the issue is in some error in how I'm calling the async post() function, but I don't know what to change.

EDIT-

These are my headers in create.php. They accept content type - application/json so I'm not sure why I can't add that to my fetch ajax requests without getting errors

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, OPTIONS');
  header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, 
  Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Authorization');
```

Comment: The 500 happened on the server in the PHP code, typically a fatal error. You'll need to check the server's error log for greater details about the cause of the 500 error. It won't be visible from the JS client side unless PHP is configured with `display_errors = On`, and the you'd need to dig into the AJAX response to see the error.

Comment: you seem to have changed more about the request than just the use of async/await in the JS. Headers have changed, and the way you deal with the response has changed. since the 500 error indicates that a problem occurred on the server, the problem is prior to you dealing with the response, and if you haven't changed the server code, then possibly the header change is the cause of the problem. Certainly the server doesn't care whether you used async/await etc in JS or not: it doesn't know.So check your server logs in case it's the headers, or it's just coincidence and there's a different problem

Comment: (P.S. you said it yourself: "_my code in my async function is **mostly** the same_" (my bold) . So the most obvious first debug step (apart from checking your error logs) is to remove the various changes one by one until it starts working again. Then you can narrow down the problem.)

Comment: @ADyson  ok you were right. I removed everything from new Headers and made it empty and now it is working. Before this I had another issue with this function and answers on here said to add that to fix it, but I didn't expect it to cause the issue. Thanks

Comment: Ok glad you solved it. If you want some insight into exactly why they were causing a problem you'd have to show us the relevant lines of code from create.php

Comment: @ADyson  updated question with my headers for create.php at the end.

Comment: Thanks. The first warning you got happened on line 7. Which of those is considered line 7 in your create.php file?

Comment: P.s. "They accept content type - application/json ". No...the commands above are _sending_ headers as part of your _response_. It's not a list of headers that are allowed in the _request_. (Actually the last line of your snippet _is_ a command telling the browser which request headers are permitted when it's a CORS request, but that list appears to permit the content-type headers. In fact it lists it twice, which perhaps is not a good thing. "Accepts" request headers should be permitted by default and don't need to be listed in that list.)

Comment: @ADyson it is this header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers,Content-Type,Access-Control-Allow-Methods, X-Requested-With'); I removed the repeated headers that I had in it, but this wasn't causing the error because even with those headers repeated the error stayed the same.

Comment: Also...putting Access-Control-Allow-Headers and Access-Control-Allow-Methods in the list of allowed request headers makes no sense because they are response-only headers. Sending them in a request would make no logical sense and a webserver would ignore them if it received them. Ensure you know the difference between request and response headers and which ones are used in each situation (some, such as content-type, can be used in both). The documentation on MDN is usually very clear about it.

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by removing 
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
from the new Headers. That is what I'm accepting in my php headers but somehow it causes a 500 internal server error when used in a fetch post.